# Extened of a representation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

The following is a part of a theorem of Folland's book:

Let $X$ be a compact space,  $B(X)$ the space of bounded Borel measurable functions on $X$, and $C(X)$ the space of continuous function on $X$.

Suppose for $f\in C(X)$, $T_f$ is the inverse Gelfand transform of $f$ in the commutative C*-subalgebra $A$ of $B(H)$.

For $\xi,\eta\in H$, define the map $\phi_{\xi,\eta}: C(X)\to \Bbb C$ such that $\phi_(\xi,\eta)(f) = \langle T_f\xi,\eta\rangle$. Also there is a unique Boreal measure $\mu_{\xi,\eta}\in M(X)$ such that $\langle T_f \xi , \eta \rangle = \int f d\mu_{\xi,\eta} $.

The map $f\to T_f$ gives a representation of the algebra $C(X)$ as bounded operators on $H$. We now extend this representation to the larger algebra $B(X)$. if $f\in B(X)$, then $$|\int fd\mu_{\xi,\eta}|\leq ||f||||\xi||||\eta||$$
Hence there is a unique $T_f\in B(H)$ such that $\langle T_f\xi,\eta\rangle =\int f d\mu_{\xi,\eta}$.

But I do not know how he concludes the last line. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: The map $(\xi,\eta) \mapsto \int f\,d\mu_{\xi,\eta}$ is a continuous (by the inequality) sesquilinear form on $H$. All continuous sesquilinear forms can be written as $(\xi,\eta) \mapsto \langle A\xi,\eta\rangle$ for an $A\in B(H)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Thanks, I do not notice that $f$ is fixed here.